# Sending Query Parameters in headers to Loopback generated API

Tags: angular, typescript, loopback

I have generated shared SDK from loopback using `loopback-sdk-builder` and have got one of the APIs as

`public getData(customHeaders?: Function): Observable<any> { }`

The call to be made should have query parameters in the URL and hence I need to send the customHeaders in call like,

`this.partnerApi.getData(()=>{header: {partnerId: 101}})`

The loopback API is

```
Partner.remoteMethod('getData', {
  accepts: {arg: 'req', type: 'object',http: function(ctx) {    
    var req = ctx.req;   
    return req;
  }},
  returns: {arg: 'detail', type: 'object'},
  http: {"verb": "get"}
});
```

which is generated by loopback-sdk-builder as,

`public getData(customHeaders?: Function): Observable<any> { }`

I need to call this generated API and the call (GET) should finally be

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/Partners/getData?partnerId=1001`

The above call was fine with AngularJS+Loopback, but this issue is with Angular6+Loopback

Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: that seems to be a contradiction. Query params means that you are sending the info in the URL itself, like GET localhost:8080/api/data **?partnerId=101**. You can also send the info in the headers, but then it wouldn't be query params

Comment: post your service code too, also that's not right way to send the query param

Comment: thanks for the response @Joakim. Let's narrow it down further. Say I need to pass the parameter `customHeaders` when I am calling `this.partnerApi.getData()`. Any leads on this?

Comment: well the answer to your question is that you would call the api like GET localhost:8080/api/data?customHeaders=someStringValue. But it seems incorrect to have a _query paramater_ called custom _Headers_. If you want to use query params, you shouldn't name them headers. If something is called customHeaders, it's probably supposed to be headers, and not query parameters.

Comment: yes you got it but how to call that function `this.partnerApi.getData(()=>{header: {partnerId: 101}})` so that it triggers correct?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the loopback function. If nobody else is able to help you, you can add the working AngularJS code to your question, and then I can take another look.